# Второй минимальный путь в алгоритме Дейкстры , не содержащий первый путь полностью

Tags: алгоритм, графы, теория

Есть следущая задача:найти минимальный путь и найти второй минимальный путь,при этом второй минимальный путь не должен полностью содержать первый минимальный путь.

Примеры( "1)"- минимальный путь, "2)"- второй минимальный путь , указаны номера узлов):
1.1) 1-3-5 2) 1-2-3-4-5 Неправильно т.к. 2 путь полность содержит первый.

2.1) 1-3-5 2) 1-2-5 Правильно т.к. 2 путь не содержит 3 узел с 1 пути.

3.1) 1-3-5 2) 2-4-5 Тоже может быть правильно правильно.

Реализация алгоритма следущая:

1. Используя алгоритм Дейкстры найти первый минимальный путь.
2. Записать полученный минимальный путь (т.е. номера узлов) в массив.
3. ??????
   И собственно тут возникает проблема - как начать находить следущие минимальные пути. Предположение , что вторым минимальным значением является второе минимальное значение расстояния соседей целевого узла(Пример:есть целевой узел N с соседами N-1(расстояние - 6) N-2(8) N-3(11) т.е. теоретически вторым минимальным является путь через N-2) не всегда верно т.к. возможно нужно в первом пути поменять узел в середине и получится меньшее значение(в примере нужно будет на пути к N-1 поменять используемое ребро N-8->N-5 с весом 1 на ребро N-9->N-5 с весом 2 ,расстояния до N-8 и N-9 идентичные, и тогда получится минимальным путь с весом 7).

Вопрос - как найти этот второй путь?

Comment: На вскидку в голову пришла мысль по очереди разрывать по одному ребру из минимального маршрута и пересчитывать сеть. минимальный из найденных маршрутов и есть нужный. Только мне кажется это слишком "дорого" несколько раз сеть пересчитывать ...

Comment: @Mike Попробовал , работает,но действительно дорого (т.к. на тестах в минимальных путях по 100 узлов).В итоге не могу пройти тесты по времени.Есть еще какие-то варианты?

Comment: Я малость далек от этой тематики, так что если хорошие подходы есть их не знаю. Вот думаю что можно было бы рвать не все ребра из маршрута, а только некоторые, ориентируясь на их веса, но какие выбрать хз. И еще думаю можно было бы рассчитывать заново не всю сеть, а только узлы в весе которых присутствует разрываемый участок, но проблема первая - узнать эти узлы, проблема вторая и главная при пересчете веса узла это может повлиять на вес еще каких то узлов и даже если мы поймем каких эта реакция на всю сеть расползется :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

После того как отработала Дейкстра для стартовой вершины мы получили массив d1[] кратчайших расстояний от стартовой точки до любой, теперь запускаем Дейкрсту второй раз, только уже с финиша, получаем массив d2[] кратчайших расстояний от финишной точки до любой. А теперь проходимся по всем вершинам, которые не принадлежат кратчайшему пути, и находим такую вершину v, для которой d1[v] + d2[v] минимально возможное, через нее и будет проходить второй кратчайший путь (с длинной d1[v] + d2[v]).

Псевдокод:

```
1. shortestPath, d1[] = Dijkstra(start)
2. d2 = Dijkstra(finish)
3. dist = infinity, w = -1 
   for (v : AllVertices \ shortestPath)
    if (d1[v] + d2[v] < dist)
        dist = d1[v] + d2[v], w = v
4. Восстанавливаем кратчайший путь от start до w и добавляем 
   кратчайший путь от w до finish - это и будет второй кратчайший путь
```

Временная сложность будет совпадать со сложностью Дейкстры, так что придумать что-то сильно быстрее не получиться:)

Правда данное решение не гарантирует, что второй минимальный путь не будет полностью содержать первый минимальный путь(: Но мне кажется, что это можно не сложно добавить.